# How do I swap out auto form fill parts?

Tags: firefox

Whenever typing something in a login or register form, Firefox will attempt to show me my most-used options.

However, it sorts them alphabetically.

This is frustrating, as my most-used E-Mail-Adress is at 2nd place. It takes up to a second longer to press the down key twice (or click on it).

Is there any way to swap out these AutoFill addresses to my preferences?

Comment: Delete the first one using <shift><delete>?

Comment: I still want to use it, just less often. @DavidPostill

Comment: I mean that I still want the E-Mail that's displayed first right now to appear next time I fill out forms, but as 2nd, so that it's easier to access the one that is **currently** at 2nd position (has to be 1st). @AFH